# WordPress site tier 2 sub-menu not showing on hover using Chrome or IE. Does show on Firefox

Tags: css, wordpress, cross-browser, submenu

Using Cherry WordPress framework with theme48244
Editing Custom CSS section under WordPress Dashboard > Cherry Options > General tab.

When I hover on a tier 1 submenu link, the tier 2 submenu does not show up with Chrome or IE, does show with firefox. 
Tried various suggestions found on stackoverflow, but nothing working.

"Our Services" (main menu) > "Our Services 3" (tier 1)  > Should see a submenu when hover on "Our Services 3", bot only see it work on Firefox. Not showing tier 2 on Chrome or IE.
Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I installed the EBS shortcodes plugin and by default it's bootstrap / recursive .css files take precedence.

Solution was to go into EBS settings and make the theme’s css take precedence ... or could deactivate (or delete) the EBS plugin.